# How to add class in nextSlide and prevSlide in React Slick Slider

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I know with jquery it is very simple to add class on the next and prev slide in Slick Slider. My question is on change or beforechange, afterchange, onInit to add class on nextSlide and prevSlide Sharing my code as well.

```
const settings = {
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    swipe: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    mobileFirst: true,
    beforeChange: function(prevSlide, nextSlide) {
        console.log("before change", prevSlide, nextSlide);
        {/* Add Class on next slide & addclass on prev Slide */}
    },
};
```